# Force Visual C++ to generate XML comments solely for my files?

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010, xml-comments

having an issue that I can't seem to find a direct answer to. I'm in the late stages of building a game engine with a few friends and at this point, we're looking to streamline the comments to make them more readable and useful for any developers that may wish to join the team. Since we use Visual Studio 2010, the embedded XML commenting seemed like the perfect tool, and it is! The only issue we are having is that the graphics library our engine is based upon seemed to have the same idea, and also uses XML-like commenting schema. Unfortunately, the syntax of whatever tool they used to compile their XML comments is dissimilar to the one used in Visual Studio so when Visual Studio attempts to render their comments to the projects XML output file, all we get is a huge string of errors that really tie up the process and are completely unneeded anyway since we only want documentation for *our* code. So, in short, is there some compiler parameter or option I can set in Visual Studio/VC++ that will force it to only generate an XML-comments output file for our classes and documentation? Thank you so much.

Comment: Or you could remove their comments?  I'm curious how VS is supposed to know which files are yours.

Comment: @Fosco - Those existing only in the project folder or solution? It's generating comments for header files which are included in my project, so naturally the linker is including them as part of the overall compile-time environment, but since they're not actually residing in my project folder or open in the current solution, it doesn't seem far-fetched that the XML parser should be able to differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget Visual Studio and use a real documentation generation tool like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). It handles the MS XML based documentation and you can configure it to only search certain files or directories.

---

**EDIT** Doxygen has it's own documentation tag format [described here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) but it also handles JavaDoc style comments. XML style comments are [described here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/xmlcmds.html).

Comment: You are the man! Thanks a bunch, this tool is excellent! I'm amazed this didn't get more attention when I did a general search for automated C++ documentation.

Comment: No problem. Personally, I prefer Doxygen's own markup tags over the XML markup (less typing, better features). I don't know if you have a requirement to use the XML markup but if you don't I'd recommend using doxygen's tags or even JavaDoc markup. On the other hand, Visual Studio will automatically stub out the XML markup for you and you can mix in the doxygen style markup anyway...